# Changing system volume and changing it back to previous level

Tags: applescript, sound-volume

I need to turn up system volume temporarily and then set it back to the value it was before. I'm getting an error:

error "Can’t make {output volume:29, input volume:58, alert volume:46, output muted:false} into type real." number -1700 from {output volume:29, input volume:58, alert volume:46, output muted:false} to real

Does anyone know the correct way to do this? Here is my code.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set myVolume to get volume settings
    tell application "Finder" to set volume 5
    tell application "Finder" to set volume myVolume
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get volume settings` and `set volume` are a part of **Standard Additions** in **AppleScript** and **Finder** is not needed.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is what you want:

```applescript
set myVolume to output volume of (get volume settings)
set volume output volume 5
set volume output volume myVolume
```

Note that you may need/want to set a short `delay` between the two `set volume output ...` lines of *code*.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! Works just like I wanted :-)